# Blur event block submit button

Tags: jsf, blur, ajax4jsf

I have a problem, please help me
when i change a value in my input and then i submit a button the event blur block my submit, so i have to click twice on the button. 
I want that one click on my button do the action in my input and also submit my button

Same problem when in change value in my input and then i click on my commandLink .. the action of my blur event block the click on my link

```
<h:inputText id="idInputQuantite" readonly="#                                   
            converter="bigDecimalConverter"
            execute="@this"                                         
            styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'invalidInput'}"
            style="#{component.valid ? '' : 'border: medium solid red;'};cursor:hand;"
            value="#{infoPiece.quantite}"                                   
            onfocus="if (this.readOnly) {this.blur();}>                                                
        <f:validator validatorId="superficieVolumeValidator" />
        <f:attribute name="libTypePiece" value="#{infoPiece.libPiece}" />                                   
     <a4j:ajax event="blur"  render="@form"  execute="@all"  
             listener="#{saisieEnquetesCtrl.contCohQuant}"
      oncomplete="modifyVal();updateOrigineQuant();focusErrorInput(); " />  

            </h:inputText>


<a4j:commandButton
            rendered="#{saisieMoisModel.modeModification}"
                action="#{saisieEnquetesCtrl.enregistrer}"
                id="idValider"
                value="Valider" 
                onmouseover="affichVerifPanel()"
                onmouseout="hideVerifPanel();mouseOut();"
                render="@form"
                execute="@this"
                oncomplete="saveOnglet();"

                style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:300px; background:#fadadc; font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold;">
            </a4j:commandButton>

       <a4j:commandLink style="float: right; padding-right: 40px;"
        render="@form" action="#{saisieEnquetesCtrl.clickChFerElementDebut}"
        onclick=" if (checkIfSaved()) {#{rich:component('savePopupDebut')}.show();return false;}" oncomplete="initTable();" ></a4j:commandLink>
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26585311/edit) this information into the question rather than posting it as a comment. Comments don't have formatting so it's well nigh impossible to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to remove the `<a4j:ajax event="blur"` and add change `<h:inputText` into
`<h:inputText onblur="myFunc();".....` , while the `myFunc` will look like

```
var myTimer;
function myFunc() {
    myTimer= setTimeout(function () {
        $('#myHiddenButtonId').click();
    }, 500);
}
```

where `myHiddenButtonId` is an id of a `<a4j:commandButton` , something like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="myHiddenButtonId" style="display:none;">
    <a4j:ajax render="@form"  execute="@all"  
         listener="#{saisieEnquetesCtrl.contCohQuant}"
  oncomplete="modifyVal();updateOrigineQuant();focusErrorInput(); " />  
</a4j:commandButton>
```

the above solution will work fine, but know that if you click on other ajax, your blur will fire afterwards...

Comment: We are using ICEFaces 4.3 and have this same problem. We adde ace:ajax to an ace:textEntry. Change the value of an input field and then click on an ace:pushButton will send a request to handle the blur, but a second request to handle the click of the button gets lost quite often. I cannot find anything in the JSF specs or on the Internet about whether the click event should always lead to a request or not in this scenario.

There is no error reported at the server and neither in the console of the client. This problem is annoying to the user of our application.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that uses Javascript to fix this issue for all buttons can be found [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60170152/pajax-blur-event-on-pinputtext-is-not-invoked-when-pcommandbutton-is-clicked/75948991#75948991).