# p:ajax blur event on p:inputText is not invoked when p:commandButton is clicked

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I want to pass data to back bean through ajax call on command button click. 
I have a form with couple of input text fields where each field is having ajax blur event. 
Every thing is working fine in happy flow except in the flowing scenario.

Ajax blur event is invoking when i directly clicking on submit which is suppose to be happen before submit click, hence i should make another click on submit button to invoke ajax call to save my form.

Here is the code.

*Input text fields:*

```
<p:inputText id="txt_name"
    value="#{partnerVO.partnerName}"
    required="true" maxlength="30"
    rendered="#{!partnerVO.isReadOnly}">
    <p:keyFilter regEx="/[A-Za-z0-9@.,&amp;- ]/i"
        for="txt_name" preventPaste="false" />
    <p:ajax update="txt_name" event="blur" />
</p:inputText>

<p:inputText id="txt_assigned"
    value="#{partnerVO.assignedName}"
    required="true" maxlength="30"
    rendered="#{!partnerVO.isReadOnly}">
    <p:keyFilter regEx="/[A-Za-z0-9@.,&amp;- ]/i"
        for="txt_assigned" preventPaste="false" />
    <p:ajax update="txt_assigned" event="blur" />
</p:inputText>
```

*Command Button:*

```
<p:commandButton id="btn_save"
    title="Save"
    value="#{lbl['tpdetails.remove.additional.address']}"
    update="@form" process="@this"
    action="#{partnerDetailsController.save}">
</p:commandButton>
```

I'm using JSF 2.2

Please provide some suggestions to overcome this strange behavior.

Note: omitted form related code here.

Comment: 1: is it the JSF or PrimeFaces ajax event? 2: is this a JSF 2.2 specific feature or are you just using JSF 2.2? 3: What is the xhtml specific thing here? 3: Tried a plain JSF `f:inputText` with an `f:ajax`? 4: Omission is not always good. Make sure it is always a [mcve] so it is easier for others to **try** to reproduce if they want. 5: Tried with a commandLink? Does that work? Effectively see if the issue is more generic.

Comment: @Venu Yes, that's the behavior. If you have an ajax call with the "blur" event, and a click on a commandButton fires first the blur event, the only ajax call will be the blur call. The ajax call of commandButton is "forgotton?"

Comment: @Holger Yes. the ajax call of commandButton is forgotten. Is there any way to invoking ajax call of  command Button after blur event ajax call with out clicking second time on button?

Comment: I didn't find any. I removed blur ajax calls.

Comment: Maybe... if you safe a state in javascript via onclick of the button and look in oncomplete of the blur ajax call for this state, then you can emit a click to the button or call a remoteCommand

Comment: Thanks @Holger, i will try your suggestion.

Comment: have you already tried to look for exceptions in the browser's console (F12)?

Answer (score 1):

We use ICEFaces 4.3 and have the same problem with an `ace:textEntry` (with nested `ace:ajax` tag that submits the value on blur) and `ace:pushButton`. This is what I discovered after logging click events and jsf events.

1. Click on a `ace:textEntry` field to give it focus.
2. Type some characters to change its contents.
3. Click on a `ace:pushButton`.
4. The focus is lost on the `ace:textEntry`, resulting in a request being sent to the server because of the `ace:ajax` tag.
5. The click event is triggered before the response of the request has been received. The click event does not trigger a new request to submit the form.
6. The response of the request (started at 4) is received.

There is a race condition here: if the response for the request is received before the click event is generated, the click will result in a request to submit the form.

You can test this easily by pressing the mouse button and only release it after the response for the request (started at 4) is received. The click event is generated for the `mouseup` event.

I created a workaround for this problem by using Javascript to detect whether a click event happens during an ajax request. Only if that ajax request was not the result of the click, wait for the ajax request to end and then dispatch the click event again:

```
/** Indicates whether an ajax request is currently in progress. */
let ajaxRequestInProgress = false;

/** The source of the current ajax request. */
let currentAjaxRequestSource = null;

/** The event that must be delayed. */
let delayedEvent = null;

/** The event that has been redispatched after a delay. */
let redispatchedEvent = null;

function requestInProgressTracker(data) {
    const oldValue = ajaxRequestInProgress
    if (data.type === 'event' && data.status === 'begin') {
        ajaxRequestInProgress = true;
    } else if (data.type === 'event' && data.status === 'success') {
        ajaxRequestInProgress = false;
    } else if (data.type === 'error') {
        ajaxRequestInProgress = false;
    }

    if (oldValue !== ajaxRequestInProgress) {
        if (ajaxRequestInProgress) {
            console.log("------ Start of request");
            currentAjaxRequestSource = data.source;
        } else {
            console.log("------ End of request");
            currentAjaxRequestSource = null;
        }

        if (!ajaxRequestInProgress && delayedEvent) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                redispatchedEvent = delayedEvent;
                delayedEvent = null;
                console.log("------ Dispatch event again for", redispatchedEvent.target);
                redispatchedEvent.target.dispatchEvent(redispatchedEvent);
            }, 10); // Small delay to ensure this method is called after the request has completely finished.
        }
    }
}

function delayEventUntilAfterRequest(e) {
    if (!ajaxRequestInProgress) {
        return;
    }

    if (e === redispatchedEvent) {
        console.log("------ Prevent delaying and dispatching the event again for", e.target);
        return;
    }

    if (delayedEvent) {
        console.log("------ DELAY NEW EVENT WHILE OLD EVENT HAS NOT BEEN DISPATCHED AGAIN.");
    }

    if (currentAjaxRequestSource && currentAjaxRequestSource.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log("------ No need to delay this event, because the current request was triggered by the event for", e.target);
       return;
    }

    delayedEvent = e;
    console.log("------- Event occurred during request", e);
}

document.addEventListener("click", delayEventUntilAfterRequest);

jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(requestInProgressTracker);
jsf.ajax.addOnError(requestInProgressTracker);
```